# The type initializer for 'java.lang.System' threw an exception. Inner Exception: Unable to load DLL 'vjsnativ':

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, j#

Currently am migrating a project developed in 2008/2010 ASP.NET Frame work 3.5 /4   to 2012 ASP.NET With Frame Work 4.5 My Project has 2 DLL's Supporting J#.  While loading the WSDL , its doesn't show the error . But runtime its throwing error
**The type initializer for 'java.lang.System' threw an exception. Inner Exception: Unable to load DLL 'vjsnativ': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) Inner Exception: Unable to load DLL 'vjsnativ': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)**

Tried replacing the dll but no use.
Its been understood from the online updates like there is no more any support for J# in ASP.net 2012.
Please help me if any one can throw light /thoughts on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same issue as well. I came across a small blog post with a solution to the problem, which I will refer to in my answer. Here is the blog post that I am referring to: http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/02/calling-j-code-from-net-40.html.

Please note that I cannot take credit for this solution. It is a solution I have personally used in my own projects.

When calling a J# DLL from .NET 4.0 or newer you will get the error vjsnativ.dll could not be located. The work-around linked to above explicitly loads the library. Here is an example solution, pretty much taken from said link:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (Environment.Version.Major >= 4)
            {
                string folder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), @"..\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727");
                folder = Path.GetFullPath(folder);
                LoadLibrary(Path.Combine(folder, "vjsnativ.dll"));
            }

            // Now you can use J# in newer .NET versions
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Simply linking to a solution isn't the best way to answer a question. I instead outlined the solution provided in the link.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve mine and found the solution:
Copy following dlls into bin\debug folder

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\vjscor.dll  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\vjslib.dll 
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\vjsnativ.dll

-kudos to Shailesh
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/027fbfbe-2564-42cf-8b49-4cbac8c45f92/javalangsystem-exception-for-vjslib-in-c?forum=netfxsetup